# Copy one table row to another

Tags: sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a table named tbl_persons. I made another table where I would like to make history of the tbl_personsHistory.

Both tables are identical, except the name:
This code I have for normal data manipulation for the tbl_persons:

```
var myPersonOriginal = dbContext.tbl_persons.FirstOrDefault(item => item.PersonID == parameters.PersonID);
```

Variable myPersonOriginal contains a full record.

How Do I copy that single row to tbl_personsHistory?

Comment: Thank you all for the comments. I have made it to work by iterating properties manually. But this is something I want to avoid. I have several big tables, and iterating each properties is troublesome. I refuse to believe there is no way to simply copy the object. Can it be a cast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
var toInsert = from b in tbl_persons
                   where your_conditions_goes_here
                   select new A 
                   {
                       ...
                   };

    tbl_persons_copy.InsertAllOnSubmit(toInsert);
    dc.SubmitChanges();
```

Or

```
context
  .tbl_persons_copy
  .InsertAllOnSubmit(
    context
      .tbl_persons
      .Where(your_conditions_goes_here)
      .Select(b => new A { ... })
  );
```

EDIT 2:

you can try in another way, 1st select all the data from main table which you want to insert into the copy table. and then insert all the selected data from main table into the copy table one by one as follows.

```
list<main_table> liGet=dbContext.tbl_persons.Where(my_conditions_).ToList();

foreach(main_table mb in liGet)
{
copy_table objTbl=new copy_table ();
objTbl.col1=mb.col1;
.
.
.
.
db.copy_table.Add(objTbl);
}

db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: I am sorry, but I am very new to the LINQ world, and I am not sure what exactly do I need to do to make this copy.

Comment: @Wexoni, see my updated answer, hope it'll help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
var myPersonOriginal = dbContext.tbl_persons.FirstOrDefault(item => item.PersonID == parameters.PersonID);

    tbl_personsHistory.InsertAllOnSubmit(myPersonOriginal );
    dbContext.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: I am having problem with this approach. tbl_personsHistory. It does not contain InsertAllOnSubmit method.